# mysqli_num_rows on prepared statement returns 0

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function that looks something like this, whose purpose is to check if a user already exists in the database by email:

```
function b_check_if_email_exists(mysqli $db_object, $email)
{
    $statement = $db_object->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
    $statement->execute();
    return ($statement->num_rows > 0);
}
```

However, the function always returns `false` due to `$statement->num_rows` always being 0. Entering the query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "email@user.com"` into MySQL Workbench works flawlessly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the value of $email

Comment: The value of $email is as intended ("email@user.com").

Comment: why is there `mysqli` in `mysqli $db_object`?

Comment: Plus, how are you then retrieving it after you `return`ed? That return stops right there.

Comment: To explicitly define the type of the object passed into the function. If anything else gets passed in, PHP will throw an error.

Comment: `$statement->execute();` change that to `if(!$statement->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db_object->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and see what comes of it. Error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php Debugging is the first step in coding.

Comment: and your `return ($statement->num_rows > 0);` to `if($statement->num_rows > 0) { echo "something"; } else { echo "Something else";}` if the else shows up, your query failed.

Comment: The statement executes successfully, I know this already from previous playing around on the matter. See below for the answer that eventually fixed it for me.

Comment: well, sure it solved it. But [Sean made a good point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824936/mysqli-num-rows-on-prepared-statement-returns-0#comment61221156_36824983).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
function b_check_if_email_exists(mysqli $db_object, $email)
{
    $statement = $db_object->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    return ($statement->num_rows > 0);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I will accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: With 13.8K rep you still give a *try with* as your description, without explanation of why adding `->store_result()` should solve the OP's issue?

Comment: With 13.8 k rep, I saw countless reasons for things not to work, hence the *try with* formulation. I really think the OP is  smart enough to search for what that single line of code does if he wants to find out more. All in all, I think your time would be much better spent giving real answers instead of trying to bash other people ones. That way not only will make everybody win, but someday it might be even you the one with 13.8k rep